# How to put a TextView control in Android with a specific height (e.g. 5 lines)?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to put a TextView control with a height of 5 lines? I need to put constraints to the height of TextView on 5 lines with default font on phone. How to do that?

Comment: android:maxLines="5"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:lines="5"` will make the TextView exactly 5 lines high always.

Answer (score 3):

`android:maxLines="5"` // this will Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall.